# Determine security on shared layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security, layout

In my ASP MVC 3 website, I need a way to determine user security on a shared layout page. This layout page houses a navbar that needs to display drop down items based on a user's security level.

Originally I had thought I could make an Ajax call and populate a ViewBag item, then use that to determine what to show/not show. However, this won't work unless I want to put that same method in every controller/method.

Given this set up (navbar located on a shared layout), what is the best method for determining which items to show as the user navigates across different controllers/methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go two ways about this.

You could do a check in the View:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
   // show logged in view
}
else{
   // show logged out view
}
```

Or you could build a ViewModel and populate that from a shared action.

Example:

**ViewModel**

```
public class VM
{
    public string Text{get; set;}
}
```

**Shared Action on Shared Controller:**

```
public class SharedController{
    public PartialViewResult GetMenu(){
        VM newvm = new VM(Text = "not logged in");
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
            newvm.Text = "logged in";
        }
        return PartialView("Shared", newvm);
    }
}
```

**A partialview to render this action:**

```
@Model VM
<p>
    @model.Text
</p>
```

**And lastly in your view:**

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("Shared", "Shared");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your navbar as a `PartialView` which is returned by a `ChildAction` and inserted into the layout using a call to the `ChildAction` (`@Html.Action(...)`).

Within the `ChildAction`, you implement what to display or not depending on the logged in user (`User.Identity`).

The advantages are that there is only a single action which returns the navbar depending on the authenticated user, and you don't have to worry about any of this when working with your other controllers and their actions.